# Deserialization with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my controller, which can send an json object and recieve the same object again.
My problem is that the AjaxSaveFoo creates a Foo Object but I always get an empty object back. How do I create the **deserialization**?

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a foo
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public JsonNetResult AjaxLoadFoo()
{
    return new JsonNetResult
    {
       Data = new Foo()
    };
}

/// <summary>
/// Saves a foo
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public JsonNetResult AjaxSaveFoo(Foo foo) //who tries to deserialize this!!, its always empty
{

    return new JsonNetResult
    {
        Data = foo
    };

}
```

My client side..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AjaxSaveFoo",
    data: JSON.stringify(this._FooObj),
    success: this.saveSucces,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: this.saveFailure
});
```

Foo when its sent down..
    {

```
"CustomerNumber": 2,
"CustomerStatus": "1"
}
```

Foo when its submitted (POST)

```
{"CustomerNumber":2,"CustomerStatus":"1"}
```

Comment: Show us the Foo object in JS and C#. There seems to be mismatch in their definition.

Comment: I found the bug....

The url should have been AjaxSaveFoo/ instead of AjaxSaveFoo. This gave me a 301 from the server (adding the /) But also resulted in the client using a GET and therefore not populating data..*sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug....

The url should have been AjaxSaveFoo/ instead of AjaxSaveFoo. This gave me a 301 from the server (adding the /) But also resulted in the client using a GET and therefore not populating data..*sigh*

Answer (score 2):

The object you are passing up is not getting transformed into a `Foo` object correctly.

Try changing the signature to input a string and then try and deserialize:

```
public JsonNetResult AjaxSaveFoo(string json)
{
   var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
   return new JsonNetResult
   {
      Data = foo
   };
}
```